# Como posso pegar apenas a latitude e longitude do retorno desta function(location)?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocalização

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var onSuccess = function(location){

  var x = JSON.stringify(location, undefined, 3);
  document.write(x);
  return x;
};


var onError = function(error){
  alert(
      "Error:\n\n"
      + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 3)
  );
};

geoip2.city(onSuccess, onError);


</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta isso:

```
function showPosition(position) {
   return position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: Você está usando uma API específica, que é essa

Comment: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/

Comment: Na documentação da api ela recomenda o uso da funcao "geoip_latitude()" e da "geoip_longitude()" ambas retornando um valor decimal

Comment: Ahh.. Agora entendi.. a função vai retornar um JSON Object... Então você deve usar a variavel do callBack no caso x, fica assim: x.latitude e x.longitude;